# Use ?? operator and throw in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I can't write this in Swift 3.

```
let x = dict["key"] ?? throw SomeError()
```

It doesn't compile.  (I'm using Xcode 8 beta 4 at the moment.) I guess that's because `throw SomeError()` is not considered an expression?

As you can probably guess, I'm trying to set `x` to the value or throw if it's not there. What's simplest syntax to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`guard` statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)

```
guard let x = dict["key"] else {
    throw SomeError()
}

// now you can use x and sure it is not nil
print(x)
```

Comment: @Ryan Poolos You don't need to explicitly `return` inside of a `guard` if you `throw`.